# Conceptualizing SQL Query for data that isn't there

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, recursive-query, sql-server-2017

SQL Server 2017.
Having been running simple-to-intermediate SQL queries for many years, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this one, as it's querying for information that doesn't actually exist.

Given a table called `Activity` with `ProductId (int), PurchaseDate (datetime)`

and some rows that look like this:

```
1   2020-10-31
1   2020-11-01
1   2020-11-02
1   2020-11-03
2   2020-10-31
2   2020-11-01
2   2020-11-03
2   2020-11-04
3   2020-10-31
3   2020-11-01
4   2020-10-31
4   2020-11-01
4   2020-11-03
5   2020-10-20
6   2020-10-31
6   2020-11-01
6   2020-11-02
```

And then another table called `ProductIds` with column `ProductId (int)` and 7 rows, with values 1-7:

I need to return from the `Activity` table any ProductIds that do **not** have an entry for a date from a date range, as well as the date that doesn't have the entry.  This would be the results:

```
2   2020-11-02
3   2020-11-02
3   2020-11-03
4   2020-11-02
5   2020-10-31
5   2020-11-01
5   2020-11-02
5   2020-11-03
6   2020-11-03
7   2020-10-31
7   2020-11-01
7   2020-11-02
7   2020-11-03
```

So the query would be looking for any `ProductId` from the `ProductIds` table that does **not** have an associated entry in the `Activity` table for dates between 2020-10-31 and 2020-11-03.

This is what I have so far, but bangin' my head trying to figure it out:

```
SELECT ProductId, PurchaseDate
FROM dbo.Activity
WHERE ProductId NOT IN (SELECT ProductId FROM dbo.ProductIds);
```

I know there are at least a couple things wrong with that query and I just can't figure out how to go about this.  As you can see, the results set is returning information that doesn't exist in the table, hence my confusion.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: Done.  Also added version to the body.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the date series with a recursive query, then `cross join` that with the list of products to generate all possible combinations. Finally, you can use `not exists` to filter on tuples that do not exists in the `activity` table.

```
with dates as (
    select convert(date, '20201031') purchasedate
    union all select dateadd(day, 1, purchasedate) from dates where purchasedate < '20201103'
)
select p.productid, d.purchasedate
from productids p
cross join dates d
where not exists (
    select 1
    from activity a 
    where a.productid = p.productid and a.purchasedate = d.purchasedate
)
```

If you have a date range that spans over more than 100 days, you need to add `option (maxrecusion 0)` at the very end of the query.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.  When running your query I get the error `Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "purchasedate" of recursive query "dates".`  I don't know if this matters, but actual data type of `purchasedate` is `datetime2(7)`.

Comment: @Stpete111: my bad, additional casting was needed. Fixed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that.  So now the query runs, but it just returns every `ProductId` with every date in my date range.  So for example, running your query using date range Nov 1st to Nov 1st, I get 7 rows - 1 for each ProductId, with the date Nov 1st.  I know this isn't right b/c `ProductIds` 1,2,3,4, and 6 all have entries for Nov 1st.  If I run it for date range Nov 1st to Nov 2nd, I get 14 rows returned.  `ProductId` 1 through 7 gets returned twice, each with a date of Nov 1st, and Nov 2nd.  So it looks like it's just returning everything.

Comment: @Stpete111: here is a db fiddle with your sample data https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=17d9d761ab0f27096e709a842e82d363. This seems to work as expected.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that.  I'm going to dive deep now into understanding the difference between my minimally-reproducible example and what my true data is.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you insert the records for the `ProductIds` table using all those `UNION ALL` commands?

Comment: @Stpete111: that's just one way to it, I could have use `VALUES()` too...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Activity TABLE
(
    [ProductId] INT
   ,[PurchaseDate] DATE
);

DECLARE @ProductIds TABLE
(
    [ProductId] INT
);

INSERT INTO @Activity ([ProductId], [PurchaseDate])
VALUES (1, '2020-10-31')
      ,(1, '2020-11-01')
      ,(1, '2020-11-02')
      ,(1, '2020-11-03')
      ,(2, '2020-10-31')
      ,(2, '2020-11-01')
      ,(2, '2020-11-03')
      ,(2, '2020-11-04')
      ,(3, '2020-10-31')
      ,(3, '2020-11-01')
      ,(4, '2020-10-31')
      ,(4, '2020-11-01')
      ,(4, '2020-11-03')
      ,(5, '2020-10-20')
      ,(6, '2020-10-31')
      ,(6, '2020-11-01')
      ,(6, '2020-11-02');

INSERT INTO @ProductIds ([ProductId])
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7);

DECLARE @date_beg DATE = '2020-10-31'
       ,@date_end DATE = '2020-11-03';


SELECT P.[ProductId]
      ,Dates.[Date]
FROM @ProductIds P
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @date_beg)
    FROM    
    ( 
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
        FROM sys.columns c
    ) nbrs
    WHERE  nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @date_beg, @date_end)
) Dates ([Date])
LEFT JOIN @Activity A
    ON P.[ProductId] = A.[ProductId]
    AND Dates.[Date] = A.[PurchaseDate]
WHERE A.[ProductId] IS NULL
ORDER BY P.[ProductId]
        ,Dates.[Date];
```

[image]

Comment: So far no errors on this one, but it's 10 minutes in and still running the query.  True number of `ProductIds` is about 1,200 as opposed to 7.  I was just using 7 as my minimally-reproducible example.  The other two answers so far are throwing errors.  This one seems to be working, but taking a really long time.

Comment: Please see my 2nd comment to GMB's solution.  The same is happening with your query.

Comment: I can see from your screenshots that you clearly did what I outlined, so I'm not sure why it's not working on my side.  Obviously I left some details out, again, for purposes of minimally-reproducible example, and also , there's more than 7 productid's, but I don't know where things are getting lost in translation.

Answer (score 1):

Relational databases have a basis in set theory, so naturally they have set operators built for all sets operations.  We're just used to using operators that result in intersections that we overlook other possibilities.

If you don't have a date table, you can generate a range of dates with a recursive query.  Then create a set that's a cross product of ProductId and Date, and exclude and members that are in Activity using [Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql).

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '2020-10-31';
DECLARE @MaxDate DATE = '2020-11-03';

WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT @MinDate [PurchaseDate]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, PurchaseDate)
    FROM Dates
    WHERE PurchaseDate < @MaxDate
)
SELECT p.ProductId, d.PurchaseDate FROM ProductIds p CROSS JOIN Dates d
EXCEPT SELECT ProductId, PurchaseDate FROM Activity
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that makes sense.  When running your query, I get the error `All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.`  I did some googling but not sure where the disconnect is?  Just FYI, the real `ProductIds` table doesn't have `PurchaseDate` column in it (not saying that's the issue, just not sure).  Also, I also don't think this matters, but just in case, the `PurchaseDate` column's true datatype in `dbo.Activity` is `datetime2(7)`.

Comment: Silly question - You talk about set-based approach then use a loop (recursive CTEs are loops). Why not a fast number generator (e.g., cross-joining ints) to generate a list of numbers, then DATEADD(day, thosenumbers, baseday)?

Comment: @Stpete111 - I just didn't specify the columns from Activity.  I should've known better.  The answer is updated.